# Online resource for duty-free

Tags: online-resources, duty-free

Is there any website (alternatively, application) that I can browse to know what airport duty free areas sell?

Some duty free companies or airport have their own website, but I am looking for a resource that allows to easily search through several duty free areas. Or at least have information on what kind of products/brand I can expect to find.

In my personal case, I don't care about luxury items, but knowing that I can buy cheap electronic goods (PC tablets, camera,...) COULD factor in a trip decision.

Comment: What i wish to see from such a resource is the ratio of Duty-Free Price to Street Price. In practice, I found that with exception of alcohol perfume and *some* cosmetics (possibly tabaco but I have no idea what the street price is), the price at Duty Free is much higher than the street price.

Answer (score 2):

The [Dutyfreeway.com web site](http://www.dutyfreeway.com/duty-free-prices-comparison) makes comparisons by brands, airports and categories.

> Compare duty free prices around the world before you travel. Choose your airport, your brand, your product category and find the prices that are offered for your duty free products. This price benchmark enables one to find best duty free prices, duty free discounts, for some of the best brands in the world: Chanel, Dior, Longines, Clarins, Burberry and many others.
>
> Easy Duty Free enables on-line tax free shopping as well. If you are traveling, you can order a product on a tax-free shop of your choice. The products are delivered to the shop that you chose, and V.A.T. is refunded to you when you leave your travel destination country (this offer is limited to Paris, France, at the present time). Check available products on this online tax free shop in Paris.